# UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode show alphabet as keyboard suggestion ios

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, sms, message

I am struggling to show one time password in SMS having alphabets in it.

For example: If I have an SMS with format `'Your temporary password is 33432'`, the keyboard will show suggestion `'33432'`.

But if the SMS format is like this `'Your temporary password is 6EYEWITNESS95'`, it will not show as keyboard suggestion for my UITextfield with valuecontenttype set to onetimecode in iOS.

Any help please?